# пи..абол или пи..обол?

Tags: обсценная-лексика

Пустомеля иными словами это пи..**а**бол или пи..**о**бол?

Answer (score 1):

Да неважно же, сколь лексика обсценна ("(мат, неодобр.) врун, болтун; (мат, бранн.) глупый, никчёмный человек")!

На соединительные гласные это не влияет!

А их в русском языке всего две - заветный вензель О да Е (на отуманенном стекле):

[Соединительные гласные ***о*** и ***е*** в сложных словах](http://lingvotech.com/oye)

> В сложных словах после основы на твердый согласный пишется
>   соединительная гласная ***о***, после основы на мягкий согласный, на шипящий
>   и ц - соединительная гласная ***е***: *домосед, кожеед, птицелов,
>   Лжедмитрий I.*
>
> В некоторых случаях конечный мягкий согласный первой основы *в, н, р,
>   т* произносится твердо и после него пишется соединительная гласная *о*
>   (параллельно с этими словами употребляются и такие, в которых согласно
>   правилу пишется *е*): *дальнобойный - дальнеструйный, каменоломня -
>   камнедробилка, конокрад - коневод, косторезный - костедробильный,
>   кровожадный - кровеносный, песнопение - песнетворчество.* Сравните
>   разные образования после основы на *ц*: трапеция - трапецеидальный -
>   трапециевидный - трапецоэдр (не во всех этих образованиях выделяются в
>   русском языке две основы).
>
> ---

У нас первая основа на твёрдый согласный *д*, стало быть, съединительная гласная ***о***. А ***а*** вообще отдыхает.